# Blazor with Database First

Tags: entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019, blazor, ef-database-first

I'm trying to build a simple CRUD app using Blazor in Visual Studio 2019 - I have watched over 7 tutorials between YouTube, PluralSight, and Channel 9, and in all of them, they use Entity Framework Core to create the Database and Tables from within Visual Studio, which is understandable as code-first is ideal architecture.

However my database and tables already exist, and for the first step, I just want to connect the Blazor app to a table and read it into UI columns.

How would I accomplish the step of importing an existing database table in Visual Studio 2019?  If there is documentation on the web that refers specifically to accomplishing this in Blazor, please do point me to that, as I'm not able to find anything outside of some old ASP.Net MVC docs.

Comment: You can try EF Reverse POCO Code First Generator https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator/blob/master/README.md. And to edit TT files, you can use Resharper plugin ForTea.

Comment: Try: http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4318/Creating-A-Step-By-Step-End-To-End-Database-Server-Side-Blazor-Application.aspx

Comment: @MichaelWashington this website is great!  I didn't know it existed, thank you for pointing me to it.  EDIT: FYI - I'm trying to upvote your comment, but it's not letting me, saying I already did!  Not sure what's going on, but wanted to make sure you knew I tried to do it.

Comment: That's fine, it was just a link :)

Comment: Michael's link does not work anymore, I guesst this is the same blog post: https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/34 It shows the EF Core Power Tools approach to generate classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In our company we are using [EF Core Power Tools](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools) for generating the context and the model classes for Entity Framework Core.

You can find the corresponding documentation under https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki/Reverse-Engineering. With this tool you can directly generate the classes within Visual Studio and you also can store the configuration that you easily can update your classes if the database changes.

Comment: This is the only solution that really worked for me, thanks !

Answer (score 16):

Add the following Packages to your project:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.1">
```

Add your database connection string to appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyConnection": "Server=tcp:<yourServer>,1433;Initial Catalog=<yourDatabase>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<yourDatabaseUserName>;Password=<yourDatabaseUserPassword>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
  }
}
```

Open PackageManagerConsole and type

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection name=MyConnection -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context MyDbContext -Force
```

This will create a **Models** folder in your project containing **MyDbContext.cs** plus a 
`<TableName>.cs`-file for each table in your database.

Note:  For the first import of your database you don't need the **-Force** option in the Scaffolding.  It will be needed though, if you make changes in your database after the first import and want to update your cs-classes afterwards.

Comment: I had to upgrade the NuGetPackages to the current Versions, but now it works.            `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.8" />`

and so on

Answer (score 2):

Rene's answer is correct it just needs 2 amendments:

You need to add a / before the > on the last package reference.

You will also need to reference "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.1"